# How can I tell if my USB flash drive can be made bootable?

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint, iso-image, bootable-media

I'd like to try out Linux Mint before deciding whether or not to install it on my laptop. I've got an ISO image that I've `dd`'d onto a USB flash drive (`sudo dd if=~/Downloads/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso of=/media/24C4-1E16/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso oflag=direct  bs=1048576`) but when I reboot my machine and boot from the flash drive I get a "disk error press any key to restart".

The problem is, I can't tell if I have made the flash drive wrong or if I have gotten the wrong iso image. The iso image says "dvd" in the name of the file so it could certainly be the wrong image but I don't see any other version of linux mint to download though. So if you could point me in that direction that would be helpful.

UPDATE:

```
 $ sudo dd if=~/Downloads/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso of=/dev/sdb/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso oflag=direct  bs=1048576
 dd: opening `/dev/sdb/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso': Not a directory
```

Looks like I don't need the filename in the "of=" piece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usb does not need to be mounted, use that:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/linuxmint-14.1-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso of=/dev/sdX oflag=direct bs=1048576
```

Be careful with X, generally sda is your hard disk, so sdb, sdc, can be your usb drive

Comment: how can i figure out which one is my usb drive? `ls /dev/sdb` just returns `/dev/sdb`

Comment: When usb unplugged, run `sudo fdisk -l`, then plug in your usb and run again that command. At first you will get just output for hard disk, and after another device has been appear

Comment: great, thanks. I get an error when I use /dev/sdb (which was the result of the `fdisk`)

Comment: Really? but have you identified now which one is your usb device?

Comment: sorry i think i got it. i'm going to try to boot from it now and let you know.

Comment: @Ramy, you can also use the command 'df' for figuring out which one is your usb drive . Execute 'df' and make a note of the devices present. Unplug your device and execute 'df' again. Compare the difference to determine which is your usb drive.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the `dd` command incorrectly.  Using your command, you're `dd`ing to the partition (or part of the drive) you have mounted at that location.

To `dd` and make a drive bootable, you need to write to the full drive (NOT a partition).  The drive should also not be mounted.

Your command should be similar to:

```
sudo dd if=~/Name/Downloads/image.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

Make sure to choose the correct `/dev/sdx`, otherwise you could easily corrupt your system or ruin another drive.

(On OSX it may be /Volumes/Something for the `of=`).

So to answer your question, you can know that your drive is not bootable by issuing the incorrect command :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is enough to `dd` the image to the USB drive, you might need to do something special.